# localization of database information

Tags: mysql, database, localization

I want to localize my MySQL database, I don't know how to do it best:

1) Create additional columns for different languages:
ID
Field1_RU
Field2_RU
Field1_EN
Field2_EN
Field1_UA
Field2_UA

And when load records from DB, pass to SQL-query language param "RU"

2) For different languages create different tables or databases.

So how can I localize my DB in a good way? Thanx!

Comment: Are you trying to localize the database *user interface* or the actual data itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many languages do you need to support? If it's only one or two, then use extra fields in each table with a language prefix. If it's an arbitary or large-ish number (say >=3), then use child tables to store the multilingual data for each field along with a language identifier.

Comment: Either of these solutions will result in a de-normalized database, and both will require the programmer to include logic to rewrite SQL on the fly (in the first case to change the column names and in the second case to change the table name).

Comment: @larry: Not really. `select subtable.text join subtable on parent.id=subtable.id and language='EN'`. store the language code in a field along with the translation text. The only rewrite would be inserting the language code.

Comment: I'm assuming that the subtables are one per language, and therefore the "subtable." part would change for each language.  If there isn't a different table per language, why would you need subtables (instead of a single table with the language identifier)?

Comment: @Larry: because with a subtable, you have a (text,language) pair, and can support any number of languages. You can even have multiple text fields if the parent table has multiple translatable fields. It prevents littering the DB with per-language tables.

Comment: I understand that.  What I don't understand is why, using that schema, you'd need a subtable at all.  If, for instance, the entity is "Cars", I would use a single Cars table with the PK being (CarID, Lang).  I'm not clear where the need for any subtables comes in.

Comment: I'm presuming the OP has some constant fields (numbers) and some translatable fields. The constant fields go into the parent table, the translations into the subtable. If it's ALL translatable, then yeah, just add a language field had multiple "copies" of the record.

Comment: Okay, that not only makes sense but also provides a place to uniquely key the CarID (or whatever the id is) without complicating it with the language id.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the best solution is a single table, a single set of columns, and an additional column to specifies the language.  Then, add one row to this table for each language in the database.  Using this technique choosing a different localization is as simple as changing the value of single parameter in your queries -- no need to try to rewrite the SQL on the fly to look at different columns or different tables.

However, it's not clear to me if you're trying to localize the application interface or to actually localize the data records in the database.

Comment: I want to localize data records in the database

Comment: Use one table, one set of columns, and a new column to specify the language.  This will result in a correctly normalized, easy to program  against database.